# Blazor Slow Checkbox Interaction

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a set of hierarchical data that can be up to 4 levels deep. A treeview will not work for me because all treeview components just seem to have a single title, perhaps an icon and of course a checkbox of some sort. I need 16 columns of lined up information. Here is a visual to help:

[image]

I have instances were there are only 416 rows and others where there are well over 100,000 rows. Because of that I implemented [Virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and that was amazing from a scrolling standpoint and solved a lot of lag in rendering.

However, my issues is, when I check (or uncheck) one of the checkboxes (the first dark-blue one from the image above) it takes a full second to set the UI as (in the next image) unchecked.

[image]

There is some processing so the icons (next to each of the trashcans) reflect that not all child items are unchecked/checked and the row color changes and such as I am tracking edits. **I took that "extra processing" out as a test and it still took the same time.** If that is all it was, I would be fine, but this was with only 416 rows. It takes nearly 30 seconds when I have the 100K rows (thanks to Virtualization I can scroll through them quickly.) So I am wondering if there is a way to speed up UI interaction? Perhaps write the code differently. I thought about pulling out these "rows" into a child component but in my reading, that will of course add a bit more overhead since it has to control the child component and not just the native html `tr` and `td` tags.

Here is the code:

```
<Virtualize ItemsProvider="LoadMeasurements" Context="measurement" ItemSize="40">
  <ItemContent>
    <tr class="@RowColor(measurement)" @key="measurement.UniqueId" height="40px">
      @if (measurement.IsVisible)
    {
      <!-- Visgrade columns -->
      @if (measurement.RecordType == MeasurementRecordTypes.Visgrade)
      {
        <td class="text-center">
          <div @onclick="() => SwapVisgradeExpansion(measurement)">
            @if (measurement.IsExpanded)
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Minus" Title="Collapse this Visgrade" height="16" />
            }
            else
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" Title="Expand this Visgrade" height="16" />
            }
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0" @onclick="() => SwapVisgradeInclusion(measurement)" title="Include/Exclude All Measurements in Claim">
            <Icon Name="@VisgradeIconState(measurement)" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0 text-danger" @onclick="() => DeleteVisgrade(measurement)" title="Remove this Visgrade">
            <Icon Name="IconNames.Trash" Title="Remove this Visgrade" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>@measurement.VisgradeSource @measurement.VisgradeName</td>
        <td colspan="12">
          @if (measurement.IsExpanded)
          {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" @onclick="() => { addTestsToVisgradeId = measurement.Id; addChildTestsToTestId = 0; ImportTestsModal.Open(); }">
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" height="16" />
              Import Tests
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success ms-3" @onclick="() => { addTestsToVisgradeId = measurement.Id; addChildTestsToTestId = 0; AddTestsModal.Open(); }">
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" height="16" />
              Add Additional Tests
            </button>
          }
        </td>
      }
      <!-- Test columns -->
      @if (measurement.RecordType == MeasurementRecordTypes.Test)
      {
        <td colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div @onclick="() => SwapTestExpansion(measurement)">
            @if (measurement.IsExpanded)
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Minus" Title="Collapse this Claim" height="16" />
            }
            else
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" Title="Expand this Claim" height="16" />
            }
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0" @onclick="() => SwapTestInclusion(measurement)" title="Include/Exclude All Measurements in Claim">
            <Icon Name="@TestIconState(measurement)" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0 text-danger" @onclick="() => DeleteTest(measurement)" title="Remove this Test">
            <Icon Name="IconNames.Trash" Title="Remove this Test" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 12vw; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
          <Icon Name="@Utilities.GetTestTypeIcon(measurement.TestTypeName)" Title="@measurement.TestTypeName" height="20" class="me-2" />
          @TestsNameDisplay(measurement)
        </td>
        <td colspan="8">
          @if (measurement.IsExpanded)
          {
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success ms-3" @onclick="() => { addTestsToVisgradeId = 0; addChildTestsToTestId = measurement.Id; AddTestsModal.Open(); }">
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" height="16" />
              Add Additional Child Tests
            </button>
          }
        </td>
      }
      <!-- Child Test columns -->
      @if (measurement.RecordType == MeasurementRecordTypes.ChildTest)
      {
        <td colspan="8"></td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <div @onclick="() => SwapChildTestExpansion(measurement)">
            @if (measurement.IsExpanded)
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Minus" Title="Collapse this Test" height="16" />
            }
            else
            {
              <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" Title="Expand this Test" height="16" />
            }
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-link p-0" @onclick="() => SwapChildTestInclusion(measurement)">
            <Icon Name="@ChildTestIconState(measurement)" />
          </button>
        </td>
        <td>@measurement.TestDescription (@measurement.TestName)</td>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
      }
      <!-- Marker columns -->
      @if (measurement.RecordType == MeasurementRecordTypes.Marker)
      {
        <td colspan="11"></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input me-0" title="Include in Claim" checked="@measurement.IncludeInClaim" @onclick="() => IncludeInClaimSwap(measurement)" /></td>
        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input me-0" title="Include in Program Map" checked="@measurement.IncludeInProgramMap" @onclick="() => IncludeInProgramMapSwap(measurement)" /></td>
        <td>@measurement.MeasurementName (@measurement.MarkerName)</td>
        {
          var editable = EditableLimits(measurement);
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(!editable)" @bind="measurement.LowerLimit" @oninput="(e) => AlterLimit(true, measurement, e)" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" disabled="@(!editable)" @bind="measurement.UpperLimit" @oninput="(e) => AlterLimit(false, measurement, e)" /></td>
        }
      }
    }
  </tr>
</ItemContent>
<Placeholder>
  <tr><td colspan="16">Please wait...</td></tr>
</Placeholder>
</Virtualize>
```

Here is what happens when you click that checkbox (no difference in time even when it was just `@onclick="() => measurement.IncludeInClaim = !measurement.IncludeInClaim`):

```
public void IncludeInClaimSwap(PerformanceClaimMeasurementGridViewModel measurement)
{
  measurement.IncludeInClaim = !measurement.IncludeInClaim;
  CheckForAlteration(measurement);
  StateHasChanged();
}
```

Near the bottom of the images, you can see the totals of what I am calling the `EditState` -  I forced those to all be 0 which didn't change timing at all. Here is one example of what those properties are:

```
public int TotalAlterations => AllMeasurements.Count(x => x.EditState != EditStates.Unaltered);
```

I can put more code in here for reference if anyone needs it, but I am just wondering if I should use some other technique, any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1 With ***Some*** Positive News**

Let me address those that posted:

@mrc-aka-shaun-curtis `CheckForAlterations` notes below. Yes, I have implemented `Virtualize` which I mentioned and gave a link and my code to as well as the `ItemProvider`. Totally awesome alteration! Unclear what you mean *complete Virtualize fetch or refresh*.

@bennyboy1973 My data request and the post processing I was/am doing was never the issue. Perhaps a second or two for big data and then my post processing never even hit 1/4 of a second. I can't do parent and child loading separate, but this is fixed anyway (read below.) As for the separate components, that seems like a bit of overhead that would only make it worse. My current rewrite of the HTML is a bit more streamlined but still does everything it initially did.

---

**Now on to the update**

One of the things that was slowing things down was the `CheckForAlterations` which simply compared 4 fields (like `LowerLimit`) on my model with copied (when initially downloaded) to `InitialLowerLimit` and based on that would determine if the item was `Altered`, `Unaltered` or `Deleted`.  This is not that bad, but it was run on the enumeration inside a `.ForEach` which seemed to slow things down.

**The Good News**

I wound up rewriting it and adding functionality step by step to see where it started to lag. Turns out, I got the entire grid in with all of the visual functionality working even with >100K rows. Checking and unchecking boxes were speedy!

**The Bad News and new question**

Then I went to the final part where those green buttons come into play. These pop up modals where I can add something at each level. I started with the first one (the Add Visgrades) got it coded and Bam! Checkbox interaction was slow, even if I never opened the modal.

So I thought I would pull the modal code (which was raw on the page) into a separate component. That yielded no difference, still slow.

Nothing in the Modal component screams at me as to why it would slow down. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal @ModalClass" id="@Id" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="display: @ModalDisplay">
  <div class="modal-dialog @Size modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        @if (ModalHeader != null)
        {
          @ModalHeader
        }
        else
        {
          <h2 class="modal-title">@ModalTitle</h2>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" @onclick="() => Close()"></button>
        }
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        @ModalBody
      </div>
      @if (ModalFooter != null)
      {
        <div class="modal-footer">
          @ModalFooter
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@if (ShowBackdrop)
{
  <div class="modal-backdrop fade show" @onclick="() => Close()"></div>
}
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class Modal
{
  public string ModalDisplay = "none;";
  public string ModalClass = "fade";
  public bool ShowBackdrop = false;

  [Parameter]
  public String Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

  [Parameter]
  public String ModalTitle { get; set; } = "Modal";

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ModalHeader { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ModalBody { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ModalFooter { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string Size { get; set; } = "modal-xl";

  public void Open()
  {
    ModalDisplay = "block;";
    ModalClass = "show";
    ShowBackdrop = true;
    StateHasChanged();
  }

  public void Close()
  {
    ModalDisplay = "none;";
    ModalClass = "";
    ShowBackdrop = false;
    StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

And I suppose for completeness, here was the implementation on the page:

```
<Modal @ref="AddVisgradeModal" ModalTitle="Add Visgrades" Size="modal-md">
  <ModalBody>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card border-0">
          <label class="form-label">Selct additional visgrade(s)</label>
          <RadzenListBox AllowFiltering="true"
                       FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                       Multiple="true"
                       AllowClear="true"
                       @bind-Value="@selectedVisgradeIds"
                       Data="@AvailableVisGrades"
                       TextProperty="DisplayName"
                       ValueProperty="ComboId"
                       TValue="IEnumerable<string>"
                       Style="height: 50vh;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ModalBody>
  <ModalFooter>
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="AddVisgrades">
        <Icon Name="IconNames.Plus" height="16" /> Add Selected Visgrade(s)
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="() => AddVisgradeModal.Close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </ModalFooter>
</Modal>
```

I have to believe it is a javascript thing with bootstrap or something. Recently BlazorStrap was added to the project, I am going to check that out and cross my fingers.

***NOPE***

BlazorStrap produces the same lag...

***Different Modal Component Test***

So I tried [this](https://github.com/erossini/BlazorModalDialog) simple implementation.

Where here is the component I created with that pattern.

```
<div class="modal fade show" id="myModal" style="display:block; background-color: rgba(10,10,10,.8);" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">@Title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" @onclick="@ModalCancel">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        @Content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public ModalDialogType DialogType { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public EventCallback<bool> OnClose { get; set; }
  [Parameter] public RenderFragment Content { get; set; }

  private Task ModalCancel() => OnClose.InvokeAsync(false);

  private Task ModalOk() => OnClose.InvokeAsync(true);

  public enum ModalDialogType
  {
    Ok,
    OkCancel,
    DeleteCancel,
    YesNo
  }
}
```

And then on my page, has the following:

```
@if (DeleteDialogOpen == true)
{
  <ModalTest Title="Please Work" OnClose="() => DeleteDialogOpen = false">
    <Content>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card border-0">
            <label class="form-label">Select additional Visgrade(s)</label>
            <RadzenListBox AllowFiltering="true"
                           FilterCaseSensitivity="FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
                           Multiple="true"
                           AllowClear="true"
                           @bind-Value="@selectedVisgradePairs"
                           Data="@AvailableVisGrades"
                           TextProperty="DisplayName"
                           ValueProperty="ComboId"
                           TValue="IEnumerable<string>"
                           Style="height: 50vh;" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Content>
  </ModalTest>
}
```

This showed promise, at least at first. The checkboxes worked great on the page. Once I clicked the Add Visgrade button, which then displayed the modal, the checkboxes within the component were slow and there are only 126 of them (full dialog shown below):

[image]

If I then close the modal, the page still works nice and fast. Also, the more items are on the main pages Virtualize helper, the longer it takes for the check to visually show in the modal.

*I wonder if there are a ton of javascript callbacks being attached unattached or something?*

**UPDATE 2**

I thought that perhaps there was an issue with the [RadzenListBox](https://blazor.radzen.com/listbox) interacting for some reason, so I just made a `ul` with all 126 checkboxes instead on the modal and nothing changed (still slow when modal is visible.)

I then took the modal out of the equation thinking perhaps something "on top" of the `Virtualize` area was causing an issue and just had a row with this `ul` and `li` set of checkboxes. The button that normally would show the modal not just shows the row. Same result, slow relative to number of items in `Virtualize.` Even the `Virtualize` grid checkboxes were slow.

Comment: There are a few things I'd do.  First, I'd check breakpoints on the data access, especially making sure that data is not being re-loading every time a state change causes a re-render.  Second, I'd load only parent nodes at first, probably with a filter box, and add child nodes only on demand (i.e. when you toggle a parent node open).  Finally, I'd add a textbox at the top for debug messages and start throwing data into it: timestamps, number of records, messages that this-or-that code is being run, etc.

Comment: Also, instead of having this huge page, I'd have a separate component for each distinct level of data: `tests.razor`, `marker.razor` etc.

Answer (score 0):

More questions and places to look rather than a straight answer.

The click event calls `IncludeInClaimSwap` which should run some backend code and change the state of the checkbox in the Renderer.  The only DOM changes should be to the input.  Therefore quick.

But it's not, so:

1. What does `CheckForAlteration` actually do?
2. How does it affect the DOM?
3. How have you implemented Virtualize.
4. How have you implemented `ItemsProvider`?
5. Are you kicking off a complete Virtualize fetch or refresh?

You don't need the `StateHasChanged` in `IncludeInClaimSwap`. It gets called implicitly by the BlazorUI event handler.  That said, it won't make a different.

#### Update

Forget the `Virtualize fetch or refresh` as you've now implemented the ItemProvider.  I pass the following class with all my List requests to the data pipeline (I use Dynamic Linq).

```
public class ListOptions
{
    public string FilterExpression { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string SortExpression { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 20 ;
    public int StartRecord { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

On the modal front, take a look at this article [Modal Dialog](https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/Modal-Dialog.html), which shows how to implement a simple async modal dialog wrapper for any component.

If things go from fast to slow, it's almost certain there's a lot of re-rendering going on - possibly to do with the modal dialogs.  Try my Modal implementation.

On `.ForEach`, I saw some benchmarking the other day that showed it was the slowest iterator by a long way.  Use `foreach(var item in list)` for larger lists.

### Second update

IModalDialog defines:

```
public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions options) where TModal : IComponent;
```

And BaseModal:

```
public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions options) where TModal : IComponent
  {
 ....
     return this._ModalTask.Task;
  }
```

The reason for the constraint is to ensure the class passed is a component - all components must implement `IComponent`.

Comment: Thanks @MrC-aka-Shaun-Curtis - the `CheckForAlterations` simply compared values against initial values for 4 properties like `LowerLimit == InitialLowerLimit` and was not specifically one of the issues, that was in a lists `.ForEach` loop which slowed it down. I have refactored that and things work better. I added more to my post and have partially figured out why, but not there is a new question.

Comment: @Grandizer.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I am trying to implement your dialog. The url and the github do not quite match but I have moved pass that. My only issue though is this line: `public Task<ModalResult> ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions options) where TModal : IComponent`

The code is the same in the class as well as in the interface.

The error is: The constraints for type parameter 'TModal' of method 'ModalDialogBase.ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions)' must match the constraints for type parameter 'TModal' of interface method 'IModalDialog.ShowAsync<TModal>(ModalOptions)'

Comment: See comment in the answer.  The error suggests you are trying to pass a class that is not a component as `TModal` i.e. doesn't implement `IComponent`.   Check that whatever you are passing is a component - `ComponentBase` implements `IComponent`.

Comment: turns out in my most recent update 2, the modal is not the issue. Seems to be anything else on the page is the issue. I am going to look into Mr-Magoo's answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are not free - you use a lot. Try changing all your event handlers to use methods  directly.

So, instead of this sort of thing

```cs
@onclick="() => IncludeInClaimSwap(measurement)"
```

add a method to the type of `measurement` such that you can do this

```cs
@onclick=measurement.IncludeInClaimSwap
```

It may also be slow to re-render because you are rendering all these inputs in the same component and every user interaction (like clicking a checkbos) is going to re-render the whole virtualised table which means rendering internally, checking for changes on hundreds of thousands of rendered nodes, and then updating the DOM - and without being able to monitor I can't say for sure, but that could be a pretty big workload for a single checkbox.

In this case, I would definitely consider whether the cost of using more components would actually be worth it to reduce the unwanted renders.